# Different deploys for different servers with custom war assembly

Tags: maven

I have a project that have to be deployed to different servers.
Now it's a modularized project separated in two.

```
/
-pom.xml
    /main
        -pom.xml
    /web
        -pom.xml
```

The product it's mostly the same for all the servers. 
The thing is I have different HTML/CSS/JS/IMG files that it depends of where I'm going to make the deploy 
and some modules in the core are different too.

I was reading how to do it and I have found three options:

```
1) profiles
2) assembly
3) war overlay
```

I want to do it the best (and easy) possible way. Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 0):

I would use war overlays. Then you built your applications once and then just provide separate versions via overlay.

Comment: I was going to use assembly, why I should choose overlay over it?